# Pull record with latest date from xml stream

Tags: .net, xml, datatable

I am being provided with an xml stream that is a table of records with a field that represents the effective date for the record.  I need to pull the record with the latest effective date.

```
<?xml version=1.0?>
<table>
    <row id=12 employeeId=151>  
        <field id=divisionCode>COA1</field>  
        <field id=glCode>4330</field>  
        <field id=payType>FTHR</field>
        <field id=schedule>9a -7:30p M - F</field>
        <field id=effectiveDate>2016-10-12</field>
    </row>
    <row id=26 employeeId=151>  
        <field id=divisionCode>COA1</field>  
        <field id=glCode>4330</field>  
        <field id=payType>FTHR</field>
        <field id=schedule>7a -3:30p M - F</field>
        <field id=effectiveDate>2019-01-10</field>
    </row>
</table>
```

I want retrieve all fields of the record with effectiveDate = 2019-01-1.

Thanks!

Language somewhat doesn't matter as I only need the concept, equally versed in C# / VB.NET.

I have tried several things including:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim sr As StringReader = New StringReader(xmlStr)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml(sr)
dt = ds.Tables(0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: .net is a framework.  Which language are you using?  Additionally, can you supply us with the code you have so far, even if it's not working, that way we can help you address the code without having to completely reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `DataSet`/`DataTable` to parsing xml. It is difficult and inconvenient.

I suggest using Linq to Xml.

```cs
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);

var maxEffectiveDate = xml.Elements("row")
    .Elements("field")
    .Where(field => field.Attribute("id").Value == "effectiveDate")
    .Max(field => field.Value);

var rows = xml.Elements("row")
    .Where(row => row.Elements("field")
        .Any(field => field.Attribute("id").Value == "effectiveDate"
                   && field.Value == maxEffectiveDate));
```

Comment: Thank-you, I think this is what I am looking for, and I will test it.  I do need to clarify that I am looking for the maximum effectiveDate of all the records in the xml table.